# Onsen toolbar background color not changing

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am using a page as a right side menu but it is displaying the toolbar of the backgroud of the first page before it change to some other.So what can be done ?

Comment: hi Ankita, welcome to stackoverflow, visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for how to ask a question. Your questions needs more clarity and provide what all you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change navigation color as following:

page1.html

```
<ons-page>

  <ons-toolbar style="background: #4CD964;">
    <div class="center" style="color: #FF0000" >Navigator</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  ...

</ons-page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can change the color of your navigation bar background with:

```
.navigation-bar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

for the text on it:

```
<div class="center" style="font-size:25px; color:#fff;">HOME</div>
```

and you can also change the color of your icon:

```
<ons-icon icon="bars" style="color:#fff;"></ons-icon>
```